# camel change route policy at runtime via jmx

Tags: apache-camel, jmx, spring-jmx

is it possible to change at runtime the route policy? for instance, if i have the code below

```
CronScheduledRoutePolicy startPolicy = new CronScheduledRoutePolicy();
startPolicy.setRouteStartTime("* 0 * * * ?");
startPolicy.setRouteStopTime("* 30 * * * ?");
from("direct:foo").routeId("myRoute").routePolicy(startPolicy).autoStartup(false).to("does://not-matter");
```

I would like to change the cron parameters during the camel execution. In JConsole I can just access to the getRoutePolicyList which returns

> CronScheduledRoutePolicy(0x6dc7efb5)

Is it possible in some way access to the *startPolicy* object and re-instantiate it with a new value? Have I extend the mbean class of camel with some getter and setters?

Answer (score 0):

No not out of the box. But yeah it would be a nice new feature to register the CronScheduledRoutePolicy as a JMX MBean so people can adjust it at runtime with JMX.
I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6334

What you can do is to stop the route. And then adjust the startPolicy settings, and then start the route again.

There is JMX operations for starting and stopping routes. What you may need is to expose some JMX operations to adjust the cron policy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using [hawt.io](http://hawt.io). But for this to work, you need to upgrade to Camel version 2.13.0.

Using hawt.io, you can [change cron expressions at runtime](http://hawt.io/plugins/quartz/) in a very user-friendly way.